# How can I add a vertical abline for a graf using ggplot with time series data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to add a vertical abline for the 2020-10-13 for the following graf: However, it doesn't show up in the graf.

[image: Graf]

I used the following line of code in which I specify the abline using geom_vline:

```
p_line <-  ggplot(df_total,aes(x=date, y =count,group=sentiment)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=sentiment,linetype=sentiment)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue","springgreen4")) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=2020-10-13  
             , linetype="dashed", color = "red")
```

See a preview of the dataset below:

[image: Dataset]

What am I doing wrong? Does anyone have suggestions?

I have googled, and found different solutions but none work for me :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the date in your `geom_vline` into an `as.Date`:

```r
geom_vline(xintercept=as.Date("2020-10-13"), linetype="dashed", color = "red")
```

The full code (with some simulated data to reproduce your graph - please next time consider sharing your data with a short `dput()` command):

```r
df_total <- tibble(date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-10-01"),as.Date("2020-10-24"), by = "day"),
                   neutral = rnorm(24),
                   positive = rnorm(24),
                   negative = rnorm(24))

df_total %>% 
  pivot_longer(-date, "sentiment", values_to = "count") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=date, y =count,group=sentiment)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=sentiment,linetype=sentiment)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue","springgreen4")) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=as.Date("2020-10-13"), linetype="dashed", color = "red")
```

Comment: Thank you Mortiz! Worked perfectly. Quick question regarding the dput(). Would I then simply add the output from dput() in the question, so others could easier understand the dataset?